# How to adjust my theme, so that all elements (e.g., the search in the header) keep their position after changing the size of the screen?

Tags: css, css-position, fixed-width

my theme ([www.wortwaerts.net](http://www.wortwaerts.net)) works fine in IE8: If I change the window size by squeezing or stretching it, all elements (especially the search and category dropdown in the header) keep their position - and a horizontal scroll bar will appear if the screen gets to small.

My problem: In other browsers, e.g. Mozilla, squeezing the window makes the search shift upwards and the category dropdown downwards – also, the text content is cut off and no horizontal scroll bar appears that enables the user to read the cut-off content.

Does anybody know why only in IE8 all elements keep the position? And how to fix the elements and make a horizontal scroll bar appear in other browsers as well (how to change which theme files)...? Putting `#screen { width: 58.875em; }` into style.css doesn't work...

I'm really a starter and would be happy about any hint :o) Thanks, Felix

Answer (score 0):

just **add** "**min-width**: 58.875em" to your code it shoud work but i'm not sure...